# How can i assign context path dynamically in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to assign context path dynamically in angularjs.For example instead of giving url:'op/services/.....' in the below code i want to assign the path dynamically like we do in jsp "url:'request.getContextPath()/services/...'".Since i cant use request.getContextPath() in angularjs which function i should use instead.I dont want to hardcode it because my project requirement is in such a way that the context path might vary for different users..

```
$http({
            'url' : '/op/services/saveTemplate',
            'method' : 'GET',
            'headers': {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
            'params' : \\something
            }).success(function(data){
                    //some function
             });
```

In jsp we use request.getContextPath() but i am not sure which function i should use in angularjs.I searched the net but couldnt find anything...

Comment: you are being mean and i think you dont understand the issue....it is indeed wrapped inside a function and i just want to implement the url in my code like url : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/services...' since i cant use request.getContextPath in angularjs i want to know if there is any other way to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want is to either fetch the value you need with an ajax api call,or bootstrap the url in a script tag and use a global variable to refererence the url

like

```
<script>
window.myUrl ="<%=somejsp%>";
</script>
```

before loading any other script in your page.